# Replace/Change item in python set

Tags: python, django

I'm altering [django-taggit](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit) so that it is not case sensitive.

I want to take the list of tags for an item, check if a different case of them exists, and if so, replace the found tag with the alternative case of the tag.

```
for t in tags:
    existing_tag = self.through.tag_model().objects.get(name__iexact=t)
    if existing_tag:
        #Replace t in tags with existing_tag
```

How do I write this last line?  I need to replace the typed version of the tag in the set "tags" with the preexisting case of the tag.  How do I replace an item in a set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't modify `tags`, create a new version.

```
new_tags = []
for t in tags:
    existing_tag = self.through.tag_model().objects.get(name__iexact=t)
    if existing_tag:
        new_tags.append(existing_tag)
    else:
        new_tags.append(t)
tags = set(new_tags)
```